# What is it called when two words are combined by overlapping each other?

Tags: puns, diction

Say I have the word "hotel" and "telephone." I then combine them together to make "hotelephone." Note that there is no truncation in this example. It is not a portmanteau. I have seen multiple examples of this, sometimes when people make very long strings of intermeshed words. I thought of the word for it earlier, but now I've forgot, and I'm totally stumped. It seemed like a question for an English stack exchange.

Comment: "there is no truncation in this example." Yes there is.   "tel" has been truncated from one of the words, otherwise it would be "hoteltelephone".

Comment: In *[Richard Osman's House of Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Osman%27s_House_of_Games)* this is called a *smash*.  More precisely the final round is called *Answer Smash* when there are two quiz clues and contestants have to smash the answers together in this way.

Comment: @SelfEvident I think "no truncation" is the best way to describe what they mean for lack of better terms. Definitions lack nuance. We can say that there is no truncation because both words are complete. Both "hotel" and "telephone" are completely present in the word. There's just some overlap. Using "truncation" this way, we can differentiate between cases like this one and overlapping words that definitely have truncation like "motel" ("motor hotel" with "motor" being truncated by 2 letters, "hotel" by one letter, and having an overlap of 2 letters).

Comment: @SelfEvident Otherwise, one would have to say that "motor" was truncated somewhere between 2 and 4 letters and "hotel" somewhere between 1 and 3 letters. That just isn't a useful way to use the word "truncation" in this context.

Comment: @joL This is the meaning of truncation I was giving in the question.

Comment: The problem with how this question is worded is, you didn't clarify the sort of combination that you wanted - one where the "tel" letters are overlapping, because there's an exact match between the end of one word and the beginning of the other. The resulting word has __fewer letters__ than the two original words, which means that your example does meet the definition for a portmanteau.

Comment: Since you seem to be coming to this from a mathematics perspective, I would at least offer that this is similar to the category theoretic notion of a [pushout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushout_(category_theory)). With the commonality of 'gluing' in many well-known examples of pushouts, the term 'concatenation with gluing' might be appropriate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In computer science, a word that contains other words (**hotel**ephone and ho**telephone**, both words are present) is called a

> superstring.

Your example happens to be the shortest common superstring of hotel and telephone; there is no word shorter than hotelephone that contains both hotel and telephone. It's an interesting problem to compute shortest common superstrings.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. I was actually using this in a mathematical application, but thought it might have a linguistic name. The problem with the other answers is that none of the portmanteaus they give as examples have the property of contains both words in full as I requested, but a superstring is a combination of two words which contains both in full.

Comment: @Electro-blob Don't Wiki's *palimony,*  *anecdotage* and the example I just added, *alcoholiday,* qualify?

Comment: @Electro-blob, I would say that "shortest common superstring" is the more proper one, since "superstring" also includes other strings that simply concatenate the two words, or with extra letters, etc.

Comment: I would note that ***"superstring"*** is a programming description, not a linguistic name or description.

Comment: @DjinTonic I don't see what two words palimony is combining. P and alimony? Anecdotage truncated the e at the end of anecdote. Alcoholiday works because it contains alcohol and holiday in full.

Comment: @Electro-blob. I should not have included *anecdotage*. *palimony* is *alimony* paid to someone you were not married to, hence a *pal.* p[al]imony.

Comment: @justhalf The shortest common superstring is what I'm talking about. I guess superstring doesn't totally encapsulate what I'm talking about, since two words could be combined by adding characters in-between without them overlapping. I guess I'm talking about a superstring of two words that is also a portmanteau, but I still consider this the best answer so far because it includes the idea of combining words without cutting off letters, which is what I'm mostly interested in. Sometimes the shortest superstring will just be a concatenation, true.

Comment: @DjinTonic That makes sense now.

Answer (score 55):

Note that in your example, one "-tel-" from the two is dropped, so there is truncation. If there were no truncation, then your word would be a ***[compound word](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-compounds.html).***

Describing the term ***portmanteau***, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) says:

> A ***portmanteau*** (/pɔːrtˈmæntoʊ/, /ˌpɔːrtmænˈtoʊ/) or ***portmanteau word*** (from "portmanteau (luggage)") is *a blend of words* in which ***parts of multiple words are combined into a new word***, as in ***smog***, coined by blending *smoke* and *fog*, or ***motel***, from *motor* and *hotel*. *In linguistics, a portmanteau is a single morph that is analyzed as representing two (or more) underlying morphemes.*

This term is different from *contractions* or *compound words*:

> A portmanteau word is similar to a contraction, but contractions are formed from words that would otherwise appear together in sequence, such as *do* and *not* to make ***don't***, whereas a ***portmanteau*** *is formed by combining two or more existing words that all relate to a single concept*.
>
> A portmanteau also differs from a compound, which does not involve the truncation of parts of the stems of the blended words. For instance, ***starfish*** *is a compound*, not a portmanteau, of *star* and *fish*, as it includes both words in full.

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/portmanteau) sheds more light on this phenomenon:

> In Lewis Carroll's *Through the Looking Glass*, Alice asks Humpty Dumpty to explain words from the nonsense poem "Jabberwocky" and is told that *slithy* is "***like a portmanteau-there are two meanings packed up into one word.***" Although *slithy* hasn't caught on (it's made up of *slimy* and *lithe*, according to Humpty Dumpty), another portmanteau invented by Carroll has in fact found a place in the language: ***chortle*** (supposedly from chuckle and snort).
>
> English includes other portmanteaus, too, such as ***brunch*** (*breakfast and lunch*) and ***dramedy*** (*drama and comedy*). Following Carroll's lead, English speakers have come to call these fairly common words by the not-so-common name for ***a type of traveling bag with two compartments.*** The technical (and simpler) term for such words is ***blend***.

Comment: Your answer seems negated by the OP's assertion *Note that there is no truncation in this example. It is not a portmanteau.*

Comment: @Greybeard Well, I would argue that there is truncation. One "-tel-" has disappeared. It is a portmanteau. If there was no truncation, it would have been a compound.

Comment: @DjinTonic I knew the French word for this from my studies: ["mot-valise"](https://motvaliseblog.wordpress.com/2014/09/03/what-is-a-mot-valise/). And its English equivalent is portmanteau. That's how I found my answer.

Comment: I'd say that "hotelephone" is a portmanteau regardless of what the OP thinks.

Comment: I agree that "hotelephone" is a type of portmanteau, but OP seems to want a more specific word for this particular type (if one exists).

Comment: In one sense it's a  truncation that saves space and ink, yet both words are there in their entirety-- a trompe l'oeil in print. These are certainly blends or portmanteaus.

Comment: @fev Odd to say that the English version is "portmanteau", given that word is a borrowed *from French*.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman If you check the link I gave for "mot-valise", you will find this: "A mot-valise is the French word for _**what we call a portmanteau in English**_."  The fact that the word is borrowed from French, does not make its use less English.

Comment: It's difficult to argue that there's no truncation when the number of letters has been reduced.

Comment: @MaxWilliams By the definition in the answer it's not a portmanteau, no matter what you or OP thinks. As bolded in the answer "**parts** of multiple words are combined into a new word" - note parts is specific for multiple words, not one word. In OP's examples at least one word is included in full. Not using a part of the word excludes it, by definition, from being a portmanteau.

Answer (score 31):

**haplologic/overlapping blends**

From the sources below, it appears that **overlapping blend** is a subtype of **haplologic blend.**

> A **blend** (sometimes blend word, lexical blend, portmanteau or
> portmanteau word) is a word formed from parts of two or more other
> words.
> ...
> **Overlapping blends** are those for which the ingredients' consonants,
> vowels or even syllables overlap to some extent. The overlap can be of
> different kinds. These are also called **haplologic blends**
>
> There may be an overlap that is both phonological and orthographic,
> but with no other shortening:
>
> *anecdote + dotage → anecdotage
>
> pal + alimony → palimony*
> ... [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_word)

> Haplology is a name given to syllable suppression due to repetition of
> sound. When two successive syllables have their prominent elements in
> common, *syllable syncope* is likely to ensue. **Haplological blends
> would then be forms in which one part of the compound is eliminated
> because it occurs in another part**. [*Blends—Their Relation To English
> Word Formation*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Blends_Their_Relation_To_English_Word_Fo/Z6H7DAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22haplologic%20blends%22&pg=PT19&printsec=frontcover) (2014)

One of the examples given in *Blends* (in addition to Wiki's *anecdotage*) is *alcoholiday,* in which, like the OP's *ho[tel]ephone*, both overlapping words are present in their entirety: alco[hol]iday.

> Another type [of error] includes "Haplologies and other Telescopic Errors"
> ...i.e. when a word is shortened or two words are merged by deleting
> one or more syllables or syllable parts to ease pronunciation.
> **Haplology generally occurs when two words are blended where they
> overlap**, as in *muddle←mud puddle*, or *nitness←Nixon witness*. **Overlapping blends**, such as
> *adaptitute [1806) adapt + aptitude* (OED3), or *affluenza [1973]← affluence + influenza* ... could have their origin or model in
> spontaneous phenomena like the above-mentioned haplologies. [*Analogy in Word Formation*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Analogy_in_Word_formation/RYklDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=haplology%20blend&pg=PA110&printsec=frontcover) (2017)

> **haplology**
> contraction of a word by omission of one or more similar sounds or syllables (as in mineralogy for hypothetical
> mineralology or \ˈprä-blē\ for probably)
>
> American philologist Maurice Bloomfield recognized the tendency to
> drop one of a pair of similar syllables a little over a hundred years
> ago. He has been credited with joining the combining form "hapl-" or
> "haplo-" (meaning "single") with "-logy" (meaning "oral or written
> expression") to create "haplology" as a name for the phenomenon.
> [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/haplology)

Comment: Wikipedia in turn cites [Wood (1911), 'Iterative, Blends and "Streckformen"'](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/pdf/10.1086/mp.9.2.3693731). The term "haplologic blend" appears on the 21st page (numbered 21 at the top and 177 at the bottom). The trouble is, most of Wood's examples are not the sort of thing OP is after. Some are (French "vaticanaille", English "refereader"), but most have only a part of the syllable repeated.

Comment: @TimPederick (1) See the definition/example I've added. (2) You say *most*, so some of Wood's examples *are* a whole syllable? (3) the m-w definition of haplology has "one or more similar sounds or syllables." Wiki's definition is supported.

Comment: OP’s example has the words joined by a *complete* overlap of the end of one and the start of the other. Wood’s example "vaticanaille = vatican + canaille" certainly meets this criterion, and "Refereader = Referee + reader" arguably does (in sound if not in spelling). But most of his examples don’t, e.g. "coronotions = coronation + notions", German "balaff" = "baff + blaff". So I’m wondering whether "haplological blend" is specific enough to what OP wants, if it encompasses these other examples too.

Comment: I don't think it *has* to be syllables, and I misspoke when I implied that it did. By "part of the syllable", what I really meant was a part that isn't a strict suffix of the first word and prefix of the second. The "n…tion" in "coronation + notions"; the "aff"/"b" in "baff + blaff". Interestingly, some of Wood's examples in the previous section ("blends", not "haplological blends") fit OP's criterion just fine: "sneekretly" = "sneak + secretly", "wegotism" = "we + egotism".

Comment: See the OP's comment under the checked answer.

Comment: Why isn't that word "haplogic"?

Comment: I've added m-w's note about the term's origin.

Answer (score 4):

As others have stated, I believe your assertion that it not a portmanteau is incorrect.

[Tom7](http://tom7.org/portmantout/) has a video describing portmanteaus and takes it to the extreme by creating one containing every word in English.

Comment: I think the assertion is not that it is not a portmanteau but rather that the *category* they are interested in is not portmanteaus.  Most portmanteaus do not include the entirety of bot words.

Answer (score -2):

All the other answers plus sometimes concatenation.

Comment: This would benefit from a definition and your explanation of how it fits.  Please take a moment to see the [help] on how to answer, and welcome.

Comment: Concatenation is putting one word immediately after the other, not combining the overlaps.

Comment: Thankyou barmar, I have only ever seen it used and not had it explained to me so just knew it was some attachment of two words.

Comment: @ColinEllis If you took the time to see the tour of this site, you probably noticed that one line answers are discouraged here. You answer could be improved by providing some research. i would encourage you to do that.

Comment: Fev I'm 54,i took a tour of the site and its rules along with a hundred others a couple of decades ago, there are a lot of commonalities that make sense, politeness, logical structured arguments, sentences etc. Thank you for taking the time to help me fit in better.

Comment: @ColinEllis If you look around at the other answers, you will see that they are a bit more elaborate. They provide definitions and links to dictionaries or reputable sources, It would be good to explain why you think "concatenation" is a good option. I am sure you would be able to manage that :-) Otherwise people will downvote as one user has already done so, probably to sanction your so minor edit to your answer.